# ClickOnce Icon when updating the app doesn't use my default application icon

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, clickonce

I am deploying with ClickOnce.  My app has a default icon, which is used fine.  When updating (via clickonce) the update window does not use my application icon (it uses the default no icon).

I can't find a way to change this to use my application icon.  Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. It's hard to find documentation on the "installer" part of clickonce. I've been banging my head on this for two days now.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can do this with the MageUI utility. I have not tried this. I'm still looking for a way to do this from Visual Studio.

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/dotnet/after-three-years-i-discover-how-to-choose-a-clickonce-icon-in-mageui/

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your icon is selected under the properties section?

Comment: The properties of what? Is there a way to get to the properties section of the clickonce update form?